# How to get 2D lighting behind and in front of certain objects in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lightning

Hello guys I have an Universal renderer pipeline asset installed in my Unity editor,   the problem that I am facing is I want to get that 2D lightning in front of  and behind certain objects.

I have tried several solutions  including changing Z position of objects and even tried sorting order but nothing has been working out, the lightning always gets behind objects  and it does not come in front of them.

Comment: can you share more about your lights as i didnt need them in my game but i threw in a 2d spot light and hey presto it lit the front of my things

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: By in front/behind you mean regarding the position or layers? The second I would have a follow up question: What does behind mean when speaking of lighting and layers? You mean you want to exclude certain objects from receiving light?

Comment: By behind I mean by position I want the lightning to appear behind objects

Comment: It is 2D light, there is no behind or in front, there are only layers there are affected or not.

Comment: So I can't get a 2D light of 1 intensity and outer radius of only 1 behind my bulb gameobject?